# How to insert huge formulas in PhpExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Need your help with problem:
I need to Insert Formulas in the cells.
Simple Formulas like =A1+A2 are uploading OK.
But such as "=(C18100%/D18)100%" don't upload. Just empty cells.
Also as i'm from Ukraine, i need to upload formulas in my own language. Example:

```
=(((((C17(1-(Скидка&#43;НакопСкидка))(1-Са&#1084;овывоз)))(1-ПоФакту)))(1-Скидка_Упаковка))
Attemp to upload such formula gives an error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'Р›РёСЃС‚3!G17 -> Formula Error: Expecting ')'' in /var/www/zoobonus/zoobonus.ua/php_classes_2.1/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:300 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/zoobonus/zoobonus.ua/php_classes_2.1/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php(460): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() #1 /var/www/zoobonus/zoobonus.ua/php_classes_2.1/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(187): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5_Worksheet->close() #2 /var/www/zoobonus/zoobonus.ua/templates/account/price_list/blank_for_all.php(75): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('/var/www/zoobon...') #3 /var/www/zoobonus/zoobonus.ua/admin/outlet_report.php(45): include('/var/www/zoobon...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/zoobonus/zoobonus.ua/php_classes_2.1/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 300
```

How to fix this problems?

Answer (score 0):

```
=(C18100%/D18)100%
```

is not a valid excel formula (missing operator between `(C18100%/D18)` and `100%`

```
=(((((C17(1-(Скидка+НакопСкидка))(1-Самовывоз)))(1-ПоФакту)))(1-Скидка_Упаковка))
```

Are those named ranges (e.g. `Скидка`) that you're using in that formula?

I don't believe that C17 is a function in MS Excel, but it looks as though you are using it as one here.

Another problem lies in the lack of operator between `-(Скидка+НакопСкидка))` and `(1-Самовывоз)))` and between `(1-Самовывоз)))` and `(1-ПоФакту)))` and between `(1-ПоФакту)))` and `(1-Скидка_Упаковка))`

I never realised that MS Excel allowed you to link operands without any operator, and can't find any version of MS Excel that will actually allow me to enter such a formula without complaining about it, so again I'd suggest that it is an invalid formula.

Answer (score 0):

=(C18*100%/D18)*100% - i have repair the formula. It still doesn't want to insert in the cell. Why?

**=(((((C17(1-(Скидка+НакопСкидка))(1-Самовывоз)))(1-ПоФакту)))(1-Скидка_Упаковка))** - thanks, it was really invalid formula, words like "Скидка" are links on cells. So i repeaired it on =(1-D7)*17 and it inserts now.

Comment: What error are you getting from `=(C18*100%/D18)*100%` because it looks valid now, though the multiplication by 100% is unnecessary and can be simplified to `=C18/D18`